# What is the Difference between Container and Grid in Semantic-ui?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, semantic-ui

I just started to practice on semantic-ui and i am little bit confused regarding Container and Grid in Semantic Ui. As in general, Container is used to be defined as a width on a web page. Want a good little explanation regarding this concept.
Thanks

Comment: Yes the container sets the width and centers all the content on the page, much like how there are margins on either side of the body in a Word document.  The grid will break up the content into defined columns.  Usually your container element will wrap around your grid, leaving both right and left margins.   The column widths are percentage based, so it does not matter how wide your container is, your content will be broken up into equally sized columns.

Comment: So it means, In easy concept, Grid will act as Columns inside a Container?

Comment: Then using Grid with the container prop set to true is equivalent to using the Container component?